# Book (part of a trilogy?), main character teleports to another world where his heart issues are fixed; the covers showed an eye

Tags: story-identification, books

I remember this book I read a while ago, but I can't remember its name. It's part of a series of I think 3 books. Each book has a picture of an eye on the cover.

The story starts with the main character who is a kid somehow teleporting to another world over a continental divide. He also had heart issues. In the other world, magic was possible, everyone spoke English, they told stories about our world, and his heart issues stop.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is "[The Divide](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/227904.The_Divide)" (2003) by Elizabeth Kay.

The young male protagonist (Felix) crosses 'the divide' into another realm and has a congenital heart condition.

Note the eye motif on the cover.

[image: blue-grey background with eye in the center]